# How to right query which will work like key of hash map

Tags: java, sql-server, database

In MSSQL-2012.

I have table which can have duplicates row. There are two column(col1,col2) which we can combined and can use as key in hash map, so we can retrieve all latest row in **JAVA**. eg : Map

So if I have 100 rows in table. Using SQL Query I can get 100 row and Using MAP, I will get latest row as 20.(JUST A Example).

My question is : Is it possible to write query, so we can replace MAP part to query. instead of MAP in java, we can get similar data retrieve.

Comment: think about group by ?!

Comment: I did but not working.

Comment: You probably should add an example with data and expected results. Currently your problem is really difficult to understand.

Comment: If you table only contains two columns and/or **does not** contain any timestamp information than you can **never** be sure which of the duplicated records is the latest. The sequence of records in the resultset will depend on many criteria which will have **nothing** to do with writting sequence. 
If you do have timestamp than `group` and `order by` (as suggested by @MohamadMahmoud) will solve your problem